# How to show $|f''|=|1+f'^2|(tf'-f)$ has unique solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mean-curvature-flows

I calculate the 1-dimensional self-similar solution of mean curvature flow, and found this quesiton is equal to prove 
$$
|f''|=|1+f'^2|(tf'-f)
$$ 
has unique solution. Where $f=f(t): \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$, and $f\ge 0$.  Obviously, $f\equiv  0$ is a solution of above ODE. But, how to show this ODE has unique solution ?

Comment: Any function $f(t)=ct$ is a solution of this, since $f''$ would be $0$, and $tf'=f$.

Comment: Do you mean a unique solution for a specified $f(0)$ and $f'(0)$?

Comment: @alex.jordan  Sorry, I miss the $f\ge 0$.